# htresponseGetChunk: Didn't read the full chunk

Tags: httpd.conf, websphere-7

I have issue when connecting IBM HTTP Server (Web Server) to WebSphere (App Server). This issue is intermittent. It causes the page is not fully loaded (and sometimes blank). I have traced this issue and got that sometimes Web Server cannot read the data response from App Server.

Then I enables log plugin (plugin-cfg.xml) to TRACE. After comparing the success and failed logs, I get this in my failed request:

---

**[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Didn't read the full chunk 21583**

---

Example success response :

---

```
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Getting the next chunk
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Chunk length hex: 998 -> 
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: ws_common: websphereReplyToBrowser: Read body of length |
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: mod_was_ap22_http: cb_write_body: In the write body callback writing 
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Getting the next 
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Chunk length hex: 544f -> 21583
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: ws_common: websphereReplyToBrowser: Read body of length |21583|
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: mod_was_ap22_http: cb_write_body: In the write body callback writing 21583
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Getting the next chunk
[Tue Feb 13 02:40:52 2018] 00006f2a 0000025a - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Chunk length hex: 5 -> 5
```

---

Example of failed response :

---

```
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Getting the next 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Chunk length hex: 998 -> 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: ws_common: websphereReplyToBrowser: Read body of length |
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: mod_was_ap22_http: cb_write_body: In the write body callback writing 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Getting the next 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Chunk length hex: 544f -> 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseGetChunk: Didn't read the full chunk 
[Tue Feb 13 02:42:14 2018] 00006f2a 0000024e - TRACE: lib_htresponse: htresponseDestroyChunkedFooters: Destroying the chunked footers
```

---

I have searched for that issue and don't get any explanation and the root cause. Please let me know if someone has facing the same issue

Comment: Did you filter this? you should follow the "00006f2a 0000024e" process and thread IDs. It looks like some context has been lost. That, or your maintenance level is very old.

Comment: I have traced that thread ID and comparing with other thread ID. Still don't get any idea why this is happened.